# i broke mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002):

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

This morning I had these errors:

```
error: mysql shutdown unexpectedly. 
10:55:14 [mysql] this may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
10:55:14 [mysql] improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method. 
10:55:14 [mysql] press the logs button to view error logs and check 10:55:14 [mysql] the windows event viewer for more clues 
10:55:14 [mysql] if you need more help, copy and post this 
10:55:14 [mysql] entire log window on the forums
```

It's not the first time I've made this mistake a few months ago and I adopted this solution:
Rename folder mysql/data to mysql/data_old
Make a copy of mysql/backup folder and name it as mysql/data
Copy all your database folders from mysql/data_old into mysql/data (except mysql, performance_schema, and phpmyadmin folders)
Today I no longer have a backup folder, so I deleted the following files as suggested as an alternative solution on this forum and changed the port=3600 to 8111 in the my.ini file. This did not work.

Then I did this solution:
"Simple solution Open shell from Xampp Control Panel
`mysqld --console --skip-grant-tables --skip-external-locking`
Then again open an other shell and run
`mysqlcheck -r --databases mysql --use-frm`
Now close both shells and restart the xampp."

And then my mysql started without error. But now my phpmyadmin won't start.
I get this error:  `mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002):`

I replaced the files that I had deleted (and kept elsewhere) in mysql/data by overwriting the old ones. I've reset the port to 3600 but my phpmyadmin won't start.

I'm desperate yesterday everything was working.

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: I have this error on phpmyadmin: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused. 

Before I saw this I had launched my symfony project and I had an error telling me that it couldn't read my .env and that's when I noticed that my .env had disappeared.

Comment: and I get the same error after recreating my .env and trying to recreate my database:                                                                                                                        
 $ php bin/console doctrine:database:create
Could not create database `bcex1` for connection named default
An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]

Comment: Did you try using MySQL console? I assume your server is just not turned on.

Comment: mysql is up and running on my xampp. This morning it crashed and I did the things I wrote in my post. After these manipulations mysql worked but phpmyadmin does not connect any more.   
In the mysql logs:
2023-10-24 11:20:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=14601

Comment: I doubt it's got anything to do with phpmyadmin. The message just means that the server is refusing the connection.

Comment: I get this message on my browser when I try to access php my admin: "Welcome to phpMyAdmin

Error
MySQL replied: Documentation

Unable to connect: incorrect settings.
 mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be established because the target computer expressly refused it
 Connection to “controluser” as defined in configuration failed.
 mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be established because the target computer expressly refused it"